# Using external method in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have an external method like the following signature

```
double mymethod(this IEnumerable<double> data)
```

My data set is as follows..

```
ColA  ColB
1     1
1     2
2     1
2     3
and so on..
```

I wish to group by ColA and then run the method on the values of ColB.

So result would be..

```
GrColA       ResultColB
1            5
2            9
```

All help is sincerely appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the [.GroupBy()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx) method from LINQ?

Comment: .GroupBy(x =>x.ColA).Select(s=>new{GrColA=s.Key, ResultColB=????})

Comment: @haim770 I'm not getting values after x.

Comment: I have my own external method which I wish to run in place of Sum..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var result = data.GroupBy(x=>x.ColA)
                 .Select(gr=>new{
                     GrColA = gr.Key,
                     ResultColB = gr.Select(x=>Convert.ToDouble(x.ColB).mymethod()
                 });
```

- Initialy we group by the data by the `ColA`
- We apply in the result set of each group the `mymethod`.

Comment: ResultColB =mymethod( gr.Select(x=>Convert.ToDouble(x.ColB)).ToList())

Comment: @Arnab please check my update. This normally would work. I had supposed that `ColB` is already a number and there isn't any need for the conversion to double :(. Anyway, adding this, it should be ok now.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApplication33
{

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ColA", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("ColB", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1,1,});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 2, });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 1, });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 3, });

            var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("ColA")).ToList();

            var results = groups.Select(x => x.Select(y => new { a = x.Key, b = y.Field<int>("ColB") }).ToList()).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class type with "ColA", "ColB" properties as following:

```
public class Datum
{
    public double ColA { get; set; }
    public double ColB { get; set; }
}
```

then initialize your data set object

```
IEnumerable<Datum> dataSet = GetData() //Some method to get data
```

and perform the following on your dataSet

```
dataSet.GroupBy(a => a.ColA).Select(gr => new { GrColA = gr.Key, ResultColB = mymethod(gr));
```